# How to make applications (e.g. Chromium) to fill two monitors when F11 button is pressed for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, chromium, fullscreen

Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> results in Fullscreen mode in Chromium. For a Dual Monitor setup, Chromium will only fill one of the monitors with Chromium. How do I get the F11 button to fill the two monitors with Chromium?

Presently, I have to manually stretch Chromium over two screens.

Comment: Give this article a look and see if you have the option: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-maximise-a-window-across-two-monitors/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by manually telling Compiz the screen output size, using the combined resolution of the two monitors. That's where the limitation kicks in: both displays need to have the same (vertical) resolution for this to make sense (else you'd end up with cut off content on the smaller screen or dead space on the bigger one).

For example with two monitors with 1920x1080 resolution, you'd:

- Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager (if you haven't already, `sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager` package) and go to the General Options plugin.
- On the Display Settings tab, disable the Detect Outputs checkbox, select the 640x480+0+0 entry and click on Edit,
- Now change this to 3840x1080+0+0 (1920*2) and hit close.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERSLN.png)

Comment: Does CompizConfig Settings Manager works on gdm? I thought it only worked on lightdm? Ubuntu 18.04 defaults to gdm. Can your answer work for gdm?

Comment: Yes, @Sun Bear 20.04 does not use lightdm, I'm sorry for the inconvenience, you can install it by giving the following command: `sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop unity-session unity-greeter`

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer I am looking for. Specifically, I am looking for an answer that will resolve this `gdm` issue without needing to migrate to `lightdm`.